React Native Deployment (Google Play Console - Intern Test) - Blank White Pag
I Deploy the app and it is just a blank white page and nothing happens.
RootComponent.tsx
export const RootComponent = () => {
  const colorScheme = useColorScheme()
  if (!getApps().length) initFirebaseApp()

  const theme = colorScheme === 'dark' ? darkTheme : lightTheme
  //Trying without PersistGate
  //
  return (
    <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
      <Provider store={store}>
        <PersistGate loading={null} persistor={persistor}>
          <StatusBar style="dark" />
          <Navigation />
        </PersistGate>
      </Provider>
    </ThemeProvider>
  )
}

App.tsx

import { RootComponent } from './src/RootComponent'
registerRootComponent(RootComponent)

export default RootComponent

app.json
{
  "expo": {
    "name": "app",
    "slug": "app",
    "version": "1.1.0",
    "orientation": "portrait",
    "icon": "./assets/icon.png",
    "userInterfaceStyle": "automatic",
    "splash": {
      "image": "./assets/splash.png",
      "resizeMode": "contain",
      "backgroundColor": "#ffffff"
    },
    "assetBundlePatterns": ["**/*"],
    "ios": {
      "supportsTablet": true,
      "bundleIdentifier": "com.x.app",
      "googleServicesFile": "./src/config/GoogleService-Info-2.plist"
    },
    "android": {
      "googleServicesFile": "./src/config/google-services-2.json",
      "adaptiveIcon": {
        "foregroundImage": "./assets/adaptive-icon.png",
        "backgroundColor": "#ffffff"
      },
      "package": "com.x.app"
    },
    "web": {
      "favicon": "./assets/favicon.png"
    },
    "plugins": [
      [
        "expo-build-properties",
        {
          "ios": {
            "useFrameworks": "static"
          }
        }
      ],
      "expo-localization"
    ],
    "extra": {
      "eas": {
        "projectId": "3"
      }
    },
    "owner": "app"
  }
}

eas.json
{
  "cli": {
    "version": ">= 7.1.1",
    "appVersionSource":"remote"
  },
  "build": {
    "production": {
      "node": "18.18.0",
      "autoIncrement":true,
      "developmentClient": false
    },
    "development": {
      "extends": "production",
      "developmentClient": true,
      "distribution": "internal",
      "autoIncrement":true
    },
    "preview": {
      "extends": "production",
      "distribution": "internal"
    }
  },
  "submit": {
    "production": {}
  }
}

package.json
"dependencies": {
    "@expo/cli": "^0.17.3",
    "@expo/config": "^8.5.4",
    "@expo/config-plugins": "^7.8.0",
    "@expo/webpack-config": "~19.0.1",
    "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage": "1.21.0",
    "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "^6.5.11",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.1.9",
    "@react-navigation/native-stack": "^6.9.17",
    "@reduxjs/toolkit": "^2.0.1",
    "@types/react": "~18.2.45",
    "@types/styled-components-react-native": "^5.2.5",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^6.21.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^6.21.0",
    "eslint": "^8.56.0",
    "eslint-config-universe": "^12.0.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.33.2",
    "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^4.6.0",
    "expo": "~50.0.17",
    "expo-build-properties": "~0.11.1",
    "expo-constants": "~15.4.6",
    "expo-document-picker": "~11.10.1",
    "expo-localization": "~14.8.4",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.11.1",
    "firebase": "^10.11.0",
    "google-libphonenumber": "^3.2.34",
    "prettier": "^3.2.4",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "18.2.0",
    "react-native": "0.73.6",
    "react-native-dropdown-select-list": "^2.0.5",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "~2.14.0",
    "react-native-onboarding-swiper": "^1.2.0",
    "react-native-picker-select": "^9.0.1",
    "react-native-screens": "~3.29.0",
    "react-native-web": "~0.19.6",
    "react-redux": "^9.1.0",
    "redux": "^5.0.1",
    "redux-persist": "^6.0.0",
    "styled-components": "^6.1.8"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.20.0",
    "@types/google-libphonenumber": "^7.4.30",
    "@types/react-native-onboarding-swiper": "^1.1.9",
    "@types/react-native-vector-icons": "^6.4.18",
    "@types/uuid": "^9.0.8",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^10.0.3",
    "ts-node": "^10.9.2",
    "typescript": "^5.3.0"
  },
  "private": true,
  "expo": {
    "plugins": [
      "@react-native-firebase/app",
      "@react-native-firebase/auth"
    ]
  }
}


I use expo to build (eas build --platform Android). The problem is i build the app and everything goes smothly but when i deploy the app for testing on Google dev console i get white blank page and nothing happens. If i remove everything from RootComponent.tsx and just use
<Text>Test</Text>

it works.
is there any solution ?
